# connection failed application rejected connection jwplayer

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, embed, jwplayer, wowza

i am embeding rtmp stream of other server on my own server with my own jwplayer

it works fine on my one server but the same thing giving error on my other server i have try almost everything same but still getting error that connection failed application rejected connection but the same thing runnning fine on my other server

Please can any one explain me where is the mistake or what can be the problem that i am unable to play stream of other site using my player on other side same code working fine :(

Answer (score -1):

Maybe domain restriction on the video feed ?